# Excel formula with IF statement to aggregate multiple options on one line per work order

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following data. My goal is to figure out how many unique work orders there are (column A), and of that group, how many had a picture attached (column H).

[image]

I don't want to count duplicate work orders (column A), so I use the "remove duplicates." That gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see, even though this work order ABC1027 had a picture attached, when I remove duplicates, it takes the top item in column H, this being miscellaneous.

However, I want it to return this:

[image]

I need a function that says: For each unique Work Order number, count a picture if any of the items attached (column H) have the work "picture." If there are multiple pictures per work order (like this example), I only want to count that as one picture.

Comment: Include column H in the remove duplicates for the first pass, then filter on column H for `Picture`

Comment: you're the man, thank you